# ¿Cómo cambiar el color de la sintaxis de un tema por el de otro en VS Code?

Tags: c++, vscode, theme

Buen día, alguno de ustedes sabe como puedo cambiar los colores de la sintaxis de un tema por el de otro, por ejemplo, me gusta mucho el tema "Nord" pero me gustaría que los colores fueran los de "Dark C++ Theme" porque se me facilita mas ahora que estoy aprendiendo C++. Ya he intentado modificar mi archivo settings.json pero no doy una. gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

El tema es muy largo la verdad en la documentación ya que no es solamente modificar el archivo settings.json hay que ver la Tokens y la escritura TextMate.

Puedes ver por ti mismo en la documentación buscando syntax highlight guide, te dejo un ejemplo.

```
"contributes": {
"languages": [
  {
    "id": "abc",
    "extensions": [".abc"]
  }
],
"grammars": [
  {
    "language": "abc",
    "scopeName": "source.abc",
    "path": "./syntaxes/abc.tmGrammar.json"
  }
]
```

}

Pero igual si tienes tiempo puedes Desarrollar una nueva extensión gramatical utilizando las plantillas Yeoman de VS CODE, pero la verdad te recomiendo mejor lo siguientes extesiones:

-Atomize (Atom One Dark theme)
-Bracket Pair Colorizer
-Color Highlight
-Highlight Matching Tag
-vscode-icons

Lo siguiente es mi configuración en el archivo settings.json

```
{
 "telemetry.enableTelemetry": false,
 "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",

 "editor.multiCursorModifier": "ctrlCmd",


   "editor.fontFamily": "YOUR FONT, Menlo, Monaco, 'Courier New', monospace",

  "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Atomize",

  "workbench.colorCustomizations": { 
     "editor.selectionBackground": "#ff0000af", 
  "editor.selectionHighlightBackground": "#ffffff5d",
  "activityBar.background": "#000000",
  "sideBar.background": "#11110d", 
  "sideBarSectionHeader.background":"#4081ED",
  "sideBarTitle.foreground":"#ffffff",
  "tab.activeBackground":"#4081ED",
  "scrollbarSlider.background":"#4081ED",
  "scrollbar.shadow":"#4081ED"
  },



  "highlight-matching-tag.highlightFromContent": true,
  "highlight-matching-tag.highlightSelfClosing": true,
  "highlight-matching-tag.showRuler": true,
  "highlight-matching-tag.styles": {

"opening": {
  "full": {
    "custom": {
      "dark": {
        "borderWidth": "1.5px",
        "borderColor": "#FDCF00",
        "borderStyle": "solid",
        "borderRadius": "40px",
        "right": "1px"
      },
    }
  },
  "right": {
    "surround": "#4081ED"
  },
  "name": {
    "highlight": "#4081ED"
  }
},
"closing": {
  "full": {
    "custom": {
      "dark": {
        "borderWidth": "2.5px",
        "borderColor": "#E54134",
        "borderStyle": "solid",
        "borderRadius": "40px",
        "right": "1px"
      },
    }
  }
    }
  },

 "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {"comments": "#008000"
     }


 }
```